# installing ubuntu and windows 8 dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

so i have windows 8 pre installed i have shrunk my original c: which was 700 gb in two equal halfs. i have also disabled the secure boot and enabled legacy support. now when i boot into ubuntu and select the partition which i want to install to the only partition that shows up is the total 700 gb not the two separate ones that i created earlier. so my question is how do get ubuntu to recognize the second partition do i dont install ubuntu over my windows 8 partition.

Answer (score 1):

**On Windows, set a FAT32/NTFS Partition in the unpartitioned space.
You could then see it from Ubuntu, delete it, and create the needed partitions for the install.**
Although the unpartitioned space should also show up anyway.

I am running Ubuntu 13.10 x64 and Windows 8.1 Pro in perfect Dual-Boot on an Acer Aspire V5.

> Note that to achieve this I had to create all of the Linux partitions manually for the Ubuntu to install and run properly.
>
> > I created the following:
> >
> > - /boot (238MB) ext2
> > - /home (15GB)  ext4
> > - /     (80GB)  ext4
> > - swap  (4GB)   swap

The size of the /boot partition should be around 200-250MB, the rest are up to you.

Answer (score 1):

First, if Windows 8 or 8.1 came pre-installed on the computer, and if you've not re-installed Windows, it's almost certainly booting in EFI/UEFI mode. On such a computer, you ***SHOULD NOT ATTEMPT TO INSTALL LINUX IN BIOS/CSM/LEGACY MODE!!!!!!*** The advice to do so is running rampant on the Internet, I suspect because this approach solves certain *rare* problems; however, it creates many more problems than it solves, and so is ***bad advice.*** To learn how to install on such a computer in a *sane* way, read one or more of the following:

- [My page on EFI-mode Linux installations](http://www.rodsbooks.com/linux-uefi/)
- [The Ubuntu community wiki on the topic](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI)
- [Adam Williamson's blog post about UEFI](https://www.happyassassin.net/2014/01/25/uefi-boot-how-does-that-actually-work-then/)

That last one probably has the least practical advice, but it's got a good theoretical background that will be helpful.

Second, if the partitioning tool is showing a blank disk with no partitions, then that indicates a defective partition table, or at least one that libparted doesn't like. This is more common on MBR disks than on GPT disks, and in fact if you re-installed Windows, you might have done so in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode, which could produce this symptom and which would negate my earlier advice to install Linux in EFI/UEFI mode. Thus, it's imperative that you discover whether you're using MBR or GPT on your disk. You can do this with `gdisk`:

```
$ sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 0.8.10

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present
```

The four lines following `Partition table scan` identify the presence of, and in some cases some basic health information on, various types of partition tables. The `GPT: present` line indicates a GPT with no immediately-obvious problems (but it could still have more subtle problems to which libparted might object). The `MBR: protective` line should also be present on a GPT disk. If you see `MBR: MBR only` and `GPT: damaged`, then that explains the problem you're seeing, and suggests you've re-installed Windows in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode. If you see `MBR: MBR only` and `GPT: not present`, then you've got a straight-up MBR partition table, which might have more subtle problems.

Depending on what you discover, one or another repair solution may be advisable, but without further data, I can't offer a sure-fire solution to your problem.